# Problems with rig while trying to export to Unity

Tags: rigging, export, unity

I have a .blend file with a model and some animations and I am trying to export those into Unity.
However it looks like there is something wrong with the rig hierarchy at the head level.

[image]

[image]

I am trying to use Mecanim, and I think it doesnt work until I fix this. I tried to manage the rig hierarchy on Unity, but it didn't work well, actually I am not familiar with rigging.

According to this: http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Preparingacharacterfromscratch.html, the order of the hierarchy looks good, or not (spine - chest - neck - head)?

There is any solution for this?

Comment: Sometimes Unity doesn't recognize the hiearchy properly. So, we have to do that manually. In this case, I had to choose ORG-neck instead of DEF-neck, and then choose the child DEF-head as Head.